# Ajax call from external JS file in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to retrieve city data on selection of country id using ajax through external js file and also note that my code is running locally. 
Question is when I use internal jquery function i.e. in MVC view, I am able to load city dropdown properly on selection of country where as city dropdown is not getting loaded when I am trying the same using separate JS file.

Below is Ajax call..

```
$(document).ready(function () {

         $("#Country").change(function () {

             $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: '@Url.Action("GetCities")',
               data: { id: $("#Country").val() },
               success: function (data) {
                   $("#City").empty();
                   $("#City").append('<option value=" ' + 0 + ' ">' + "---Select---" + '</option>')
                   $.each(data, function (i, City) {
                       $("#City").append('<option value="' + City.value + '">' + City.Text + '</option>')
                   });
               }
           });
       })
    });
```

Comment: Please help me..

Comment: @Url.Action syntax will only work in .cshtml file, external scripts have to contain resolved urls, like "/ControllerName/GetCities", and in cases deployed to a sub directory,  "/sbdirectory/ControllerName/GetCities".

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug the code and check for proper url and parameter posting toserver.

```
$("#Country").change(function () {

 debugger;
  var dropdnSelectedVal = $(this).val();

     console.log(dropdnSelectedVal);

         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
              dataType: "json",
             url: '@Url.Action("GetCities")',//here is the issue, Its can not be parsed in external js file
           data: { id: $("#Country").val() },
           success: function (data) {

            debugger;
            var responseDataFromServer = data;
            console.log(data);
               $("#City").empty();
               $("#City").append('<option value=" ' + 0 + ' ">' + "---Select---" + '</option>')
               $.each(data, function (i, City) {
                   $("#City").append('<option value="' + City.value + '">' + City.Text + '</option>')
               });
           }
       });
   })
});
```

OR,
Simply check the param data posting by browser to the sever on Browser Network Tab

Comment: change  '@Url.Action("GetCities")' to "/ControllerName/GetCities"

Comment: Thank you Aditya..for helping, But I tried the way as "/ControllerName/GetCities" still it doesn't work as I get exception of URL is not found...I will try to debug as you suggested but please let me know alternative for URL issue in external JS file.

Comment: ControllerName is not just the text but : For example - If your conrtoller class name is  CountryController then You should use the URL like :

'/Country/GetCities'

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `@Url.Action("GetCities")` in External JS. This only work in `.cshtml`.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#Country").change(function () {
           var Id = $(this).val();
           var postData = {
                'id':Id
            }
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: '/Controller/Action',
             data: postData ,
             success: function (data) {
               $("#City").empty();
               $("#City").append('<option value=" ' + 0 + ' ">' + "---Select---" 
               + '</option>')
               $.each(data, function (i, City) {
                   $("#City").append('<option value="' + City.value + '">' + 
                   City.Text + '</option>')
               });
           }
       });
   })
});
```